# Estou tendo um problema com Dev C++ na exibição de membros de uma classe

Tags: c++, compiladores, dev-c++, c++14

Pra ser mais exato, quando eu aperto "." apos algum objeto, tipo eu declaro um vetor:

```
vector<int>Random;
```

até aqui está tudo certo, ai quando eu começo a digitar:

```
Random.push_back();
```

o Dev c++ não me ajuda a completar, sei que parece paranoico, mas será que está relacionado ao fato de eu ter instalado o GCC no Dev C++ por conta própria?
As  vezes acontece quando vou chamar uma função e o compilador não mostra os argumentos que vão na função, quem usa dev c++ sabe do que estou falando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente habilitar a opção do auto-complete:

Tools > Edit Options > Calss browsing > Completion > Enable code-completion

Depois disso você pode acessar a opção auto-complete usando Ctrl+space.

Sugestão: Para projetos complexos, utilize outra IDE, como: Eclipse C/C++, pois de acordo com a necessidade você pode precisar utilizar ferramentas que vão auxiliar no seu desenvolvimento, como: Analisador de código estático.

Comment: valeu meu jovem... sobre o eclipse ele suporta GCC 6.3.0?

Comment: Dei uma buscada sobre o Eclipse aqui, ja crushei a interface, já vou trocar tudo

Comment: No Eclipse, caso não tenha a versão o compilador que está querendo você pode realizar a instalação por: Help -> Install New Software. Quando você vai criar o projeto em C/C++ você pode escolher a toolchain Linux GCC vai linkar com o compilador mais recente instalado ou linkar um outro de sua preferencia nas propriedades do projeto, você pode fazer o download do eclipse por: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/?osType=linux&release=undefined e atualizar os pacotes instalados por Help -> Check for Updates

Comment: Clica em Instal New Software e vai depois na onde?

Comment: @RhuanCarlos Na verdade eu diria para usar qualquer coisa, menos o Dev-C++.

Comment: Não sabia, nunca tive problemas grandes com dev c++, estou aprendendo ainda

Comment: @RhuanCarlos Depois de acessar Instal New Softwar, click em Add, em Location, coloque: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/9.2 e ok, selecione as opções e clique em next e comece a instalar, essa é a última versão estável do CDT, posso confirmar que contém pelo menos a versão GCC 6.1. Você pode instalar por um arquivo, baixe o GCC em: https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-6.3.0/ e clique em Add, em seguida Arquive e instale. Antes de instalar pelo arquivo, sugiro tentar pelo link, pois se trata de uma versão estável e pode ter a versão que deseja.

Comment: consegui instalar o MinGw mas o problema é que o eclipse não está criando a .exe

Comment: Uma outra opção de adicionar externamente pode ser vista neste link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840009/c-eclipse-cdt-how-to-add-gcc-4-6-3

Comment: @RhuanCarlos Qual é a saída da compilação do código?

Comment: Nothing to build for project teste

Comment: Olhe esse link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699782/eclipse-c-nothing-to-build-error, pode resolver seu problema com MinGw.